# Cannot change the environment variable

Tags: osx, zsh, environment-variables

**WHAT I AM USING**

- zsh
- MacOS Mojave 14.10

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

```
$ echo $USERNAME
myusername
$ export USERNAME=newvalue
$ echo $USERNAME
newvalue
```

**WHAT IS HAPPENING**

```
$ echo $USERNAME
myusername
$ export USERNAME=newvalue
$ echo $USERNAME
myusername
```

**WHAT I TRIED**

Tried to set `USERNAME` in `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, `.profile` and nothing changes...

Tried to `unset` and reset and nothing changes...

Comment: This variable is readonly and you can change it by switching user

Comment: The weird thing is I am quite sure that I was able to change it, then I had probably messed up with something..

Comment: Do you see `readonly USERNAME` or `declare -r USERNAME` anywhere? Either of those would mark a variable as read-only.

Comment: This is not a variable that is set by default on macOS.  Are you setting it yourself somewhere?

Comment: what does `typeset -p USERNAME` say?

Comment: `typeset -p USERNAME` say `export USERNAME=myusername`

Comment: Is that possible that `direnv` messed up with it?

Comment: I have this hook in .zshrc: `"$(direnv hook zsh)"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The `USERNAME` shell variable is special in the Z shell.

It is always the account name of the user ID of the shell process.

You won't observe the behaviour that you observed in the Almquist, Watanabe, Korn, or Bourne Again shells.  This variable is just an ordinary shell variable, that starts out unset, as far as they are concerned.  Here's the 93 Korn shell, for example:

```
$ echo $USERNAME

$ USERNAME=wibble
$ echo $USERNAME
wibble
$
```

In the Z shell it starts out as the account name of the UID of the shell process. An attempt to set it will attempt to change that UID.  This of course fails if you are not the superuser and leaves the variable back as it was before.

If you had run the Z shell as the superuser, however, you would have seen both the `USERNAME` shell variable and your shell process's user ID change.

```
root # echo $USERNAME
root
root # USERNAME=JdeBP
JdeBP %
```

## Further reading

- Paul Falstad et al. (2015-12-02). "[Parameters Set By The Shell](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell)". *Z Shell Manual*.  5.2.

Comment: Running as a superuser I am able to change the variable. Thank you

Comment: @RiccardoPersiani Ummm... switching to root is not a "solution".  _Why_ do you need to change the value of this variable?

Comment: I agree. However, I also can change it, simply switching from zsh to bash.

Comment: Note that there can be more than one user name for a user id, `zsh` reports the one returned by `getpwuid()` so an arbitrary one (one could argue it should use `logname()` instead). Changing `$USERNAME` does a `setuid()`, but also `setgid()`/`setgroups()` with the groups mentioned in the user database as when you log in as that user name, that's different from setting `$UID` or `$EUID` for instance. So by doing a `USERNAME=$USERNAME` you might very well change the list of groups of the process if there are several usernames for the current uid with different group membership.